# Help me understand this diagram

Tags: diodes, relay

I'm building a kit car with a bike engine and want to strip down the original bike wiring loom as much as possible.

I'm trying to work out how the junction box that controls the starter motor works.

It has a relay that supplies 12v to the starter when the starter button is pressed. but only in certain circumstances.

1. Starter lockout pin is earthed
2. Side stand pin is earthed
3. Neutral pin is earthed
4. starter button is pressed

The starter button is obvious, I understand how a relay works, and the basics of diodes. But I cant understand how the three diodes in parallel affect the relay latching?

I'm planning on removing the junction box completely, and supplying the starter with 12v directly from the key/starter button.

The only part I'm worried about is the igniter pin. Igniter is basically the ECU. I cant tell if I need to supply the igniter pin with 12v, ground it or just disconnect it completely?

[image]

[full wiring diagram for ZX1100-D1, D2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x5AAE.jpg) (originally posted [here](https://ibb.co/iCwNRy))

Comment: The question logic makes sense with Negative AND inputs all =0 but the schematic shows Diode OR =0 inputs  meaning AND condition is High so ??? Or better just open and low must be the inverse condition (not neutral)

Comment: the schematic diagram appears to be incorrect .... when pressing the start button, what voltage is `igniter` (G/BK), when normally starting and when not in neutral?